# How to achieve line breaks in a single cell in the csv export?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I am using the Output widget for the jQuery plugin Tablesorter.

I am trying to preserve line breaks when I first export to a csv file and then import the file to a spreadsheet tool like Excel or Google spreadsheets.

Getting nice looking line breaks in the html table is easy. Just add some `<br>` tags.

```
    <tr>
        <td>value 1<br>value 2<br>value 3</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Koala</td>
        <td>http://www.google.com</td>
    </tr>
```

Js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yefw6fh6/

When I export the table in the fiddle I get this.

```
"AlphaNumeric","Numeric","Animals","Sites"
"value 1\nvalue 2\nvalue 3","10","Koala","http://www.google.com"
"value A\nvalue B\nvalue C","234","Ox","http://www.yahoo.com"
```

When the csv file is imported to a Google spreadsheet this is the result.

[image: See here]

The line breaks are replaced by `\n`.
I would like to achieve the following result when the csv file is imported.

[image: See here]

All suggestions on how to accomplish this are most welcome.

Thanks!

#### Update: Working solution

I missed the setting for carriage return. Had to add this setting:

```
$.tablesorter.output.replaceCR = '\r';
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yefw6fh6/2/)

Comment: Would `<br>` work in spreadsheet? If yes, I'd suggest changing widget-output.js to accept one more option to keep HTML line breaks and if it's set, just skip the replacement in `formatData` function. Solution is not smooth, but I don't see other way to prevent replacement.

Comment: @kjemmo note that in your Fiddle, output_trimSpaces actually needs to be set to "false" to have the example work. See updated fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/xtemLkvy/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [output widget demo page](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html#options) at the bottom of the "Options" section you'll see this note:

> If you need to change the carriage return and/or the tab replacement strings, modify them as follows:
>
> ```
> $.tablesorter.output.replaceCR = '\\n';
> $.tablesorter.output.replaceTab = '\\t';
> ```

I'm not sure what would work for you in excel or Google sheets, but you can change those setting to see if anything else works.

Comment: Thanks @Mottie

I missed those settings when I checked the documentation.

It works perfect when I set:



`$.tablesorter.output.replaceCR = '\r';` 



I updated the fiddle and export and import with line breaks to a spreadsheet tool works as expected.

[working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/yefw6fh6/2/)